# Overlapping two actionlinks and give priority to the actionlink on top

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc-4

[image: Image of grid]I'm using the similar menu as http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/SlideDownBoxMenu/ .I have a webgrid placed just below it. Now when i hover mouse over menu , the slidedownbox with two actionlinks comes in, which lie directly over the "header" of my Webgrid which contains actionlink

```
grdDept.Column(*"TicketNo",* header: "Ticket No",format: @<text><div style="width:130px;" id="div-no-@item.TicketId" >@item.Number </div></text>),
```

So im not able to click on actiolink.(both action link css of header and slidedownbox works at the same time )

So my question is how to click on the actionlink without the css of webgrid header interfering ?? (I dont want to move grid or menu which is the easiest way!)

Is there a way to use z index here ?? Or opacity  ??

Comment: Help much appreciated ! :) @BoltClock's a Unicorn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes use z-index either in the slidedownbox or set this for header

`<div style="width: 130px; position: relative; z-index: -1;" id="div-no-@item.TicketId" >@item.Number </div>`

the best thing is to add z-index in slidedownbox `position: relative; z-index: 1 or highervalue;`

Comment: Increase the value of z-index in slidedownbox like 100000. I am telling this from my working experience

Comment: increase the z-index of slidedownbox

Comment: Worked !! :) i set the z-index of the "div" that contained slide box to 9999